# No matching function call to <anonymous enum>

Tags: c++, templates, enums

Given:

```
template<typename T>
void f( T ) {
}

enum {    // if changed to "enum E" it compiles
  e
};

int main() {
  f( e ); // line 10
}
```

I get:

```
foo.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
foo.cpp:10: error: no matching function for call to ‘f(<anonymous enum>)’
```

Yet if the `enum` declaration is given a name, it compiles.  Why doesn't it work for an anonymous enum?  Ideally, I'd like it to promote the enum value `e` to an `int` and instantiate `f(int)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unnamed type simply cannot be used as a template argument

C++03 says in `14.3.1[temp.arg.type]/2`

> A local type, a type with no linkage, an unnamed type or a type compounded from any of these types shall not be used as a template-argument for a template type-parameter.

This limitation was lifted in C++0x, and your program compiles with no diagnostics with MSVC++ 2010 and gcc 4.5.2 in C++0x mode.

Answer (score 5):

> Ideally, I'd like it to promote the enum value e to an int and instantiate f(int).

```
f(+e);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always explicitly do the promotion to clearly show your intention:

`f(static_cast<int>(e));`