# Doing enum cast to int

Tags: c++, templates, casting, enums

I've a problem on this code:

```
template <typename T>
void dosth(T& value,const T& default_value)
{
   if (condition)
       value = 10;
   else
       value = default_value;
}
```

When I call that with

```
enum {
    SITUATION1,
    STIUATION2
};

int k;
dosth(k,SITUATION1);
```

the compiler (g++ 4.5) says

> no matching function for call to 'dosth(int&,)'

Why doesn't the compiler automatically cast the enum into an int?

Comment: possible duplicate of [No matching function call to <anonymous enum>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720359/no-matching-function-call-to-anonymous-enum)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, but I think that's part of the answer.

Comment: @Mooing: Actually yes I think you're right. I missed the conversion factor originally.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Your problem](http://www.ideone.com/SDGgP) is due to the fact that the template cannot be instantiated from the function arguments that you supply. No implicit conversion to `int` occurs, because there's no function to call *at all*.

If you cast instead of attempting to rely on implicit conversion, [your program will work](http://www.ideone.com/1VOJh):

```
dosth(k, static_cast<int>(SITUATION1));
```

Or, if you provide the function template's arguments explicitly, then the function argument will be converted implicitly as you expect, and [your program will work](http://www.ideone.com/RIVcx):

```
dosth<int>(k, SITUATION1);
```

Comment: @Tomalak If I change the function declaration to `template <typename T,typename DEFAULT_T> void dosth(T& value, const DEFAULT_T& default_value)`, why it still can't do the implicit conversion?

Comment: @xis19: Separate problem; there's no implicit conversion involved at all there. But, in C++03, [template arguments may not be unnamed types](http://www.ideone.com/oyPaB) (`[C++03: 14.3.1/2]`); this is [no longer the case in C++0x](http://www.ideone.com/Zsfbo).

Comment: Sorry for all the edits; I got this wrong at first and didn't realise the extent of it until I'd made all my iterative changes.

Comment: btw: perhaps another way of doing this is use `static const int DEFAULT_VALUE=SITUATION1;`

Answer (score 2):

Would this be better for enums?

```
class Situations
{
  private:
    const int value;
    Situations(int value) : value(value) {};
  public:
    static const Situations SITUATION1() { return 1; }
    static const Situations SITUATION2() { return 2; }
    int AsInt() const { return value; }
};
```

Will enable type safety. Then use it to create a type safte template.

i.e. Value for pass or fail.